# Building Runnable Jar from Project with Main Method in External Jar FIle

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath, external

My professor has decided to provide an external jar with a main method for this assignment and we're supposed to write code for the back end. I have no problem getting this jar into my project and having it run within Eclipse, but as soon as I try to export a runnable jar I get this error:

"could not find main method from given launch configuration"

This seems ridiculous as it can certainly find the main method whenever I run it in Eclipse, what am I missing? I've tried opening up the jar to get at the Manifest.mf file and providing it with the name of the class that is main inside of the external jar but it still can't locate it.

I have the jar added to the project build path and class path as well but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

The manifest file just says:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
```

I think this is wrong but how do I set it up correctly?

-- **EDIT** --

Here is an ANT file generated by Eclipse when I build:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="create_run_jar" name="Create Runnable Jar for Project Lab 1">
<!--this file was created by Eclipse Runnable JAR Export Wizard-->
<!--ANT 1.7 is required                                        -->
<target name="create_run_jar">
    <jar destfile="C:/lab.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="edu.wmich.cs1120.la1.solution_gui.MainWindow"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
        </manifest>
        <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="C:/LA1_GUI.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="C:/bin"/>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Okay I see what the Main-Class attribute needs to be set to so when I edit the Manifest.mf to reflect that it works! But I'm still confused, especially by the lines:

```
filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain"
zipfileset excludes
```

Why is it doing that if I've specified a main for my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With classpath as '.' in your manifest, you will need to have the jar your professor supplied in the same directory you are trying to run your created jar from.  Else there is probably a way to tell eclipse/ant to include all dependencies.

-UPDATE-
Since you are using a Main method from a dependency, you should specifiy the folloing in your ant build xml, and re-build.

```
 filesetmanifest="merge"
```

This will merge in the main section of the other manifest into your new jar's manifest.

Comment: but inside of the created jar is the unpacked/repacked class files from his external jar. Why doesn't it just use those?

Comment: Hmm, yes in that case it should work I'd think.  Did you create your own Main method, or are you using the Main method supplied in the professor's jar?

Comment: If you can edit that ant file, change the file filesetmanifest to filesetmanifest="merge"  Then rerun, and see if that changes anything.

Comment: the Main that is supplied in the professor's jar and @aglassman I would love to try that but I have no clue how to use the ant file to build the project in Eclipse :(

Comment: Where is the ant file stored once it is generated?  if you can see it in eclipse, you should be able to right click on it, and then select Run As> ant build.

Comment: yup, changing that one line causes the build to work just fine. Why can't Eclipse do this itself?? Is this a bug?

Comment: Eclipse is assuming that you would want to write your own Main method, and not use one in a dependency.  It is kind of stupid that it couldn't tell that the class you specified wasn't in a dependency though.  Not sure if it is a bug, more of a configuration headache! Glad it's working for you though!

Comment: I thank you for the help, but the ANT file was generated by Eclipse. Is there any way to do this without using ANT?

Comment: @user1684045 Yes, there are several ways to run your program. I'll work on an answer to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to run your program independant of Eclipse:

1. Using Ant, as you have already learned.
2. Using the command-line. The exact command differs whether you have included your professor's class files in your own jar file or if you have two separate jar files:

   a. With a single jar file, you can run

   ```
   java -jar MyJar.jar
   ```

   This assumes that you have the Main-Class attribute set in the manifest file. If not, you can specify the main class manually:

   ```
   java -jar MyJar.jar MainClass
   ```

   b. With two jars, you just need to make sure the second jar is included in the classpath:

   ```
   java -jar ProfsJar.jar -cp MyJar.jar
   ```

   Again, you can specify the main class manually, if necessary:

   ```
   java -jar ProfsJar.jar -cp MyJar.jar MainClass
   ```
3. Double clicking in your operating system's file explorer. If your Java installation has configured your OS correctly, you can simply double click on the jar file. This also assumes that the Main-Class attribute is set correctly in the jar's manifest.

Comment: I know about these methods, but my question is about why Eclipse builds the jar file incorrectly. Per your 3) "This also assumes that the Main-Class attribute is set correctly in the jar's manifest" why doesn't Eclipse set this correctly when I try to build a runnable jar that must use an external jar as a main?

Comment: @user1684045 I don't use Eclipse, so I can't begin to guess about this behavior. My answer here is in response to your question (in a comment) about running your program without Ant. Perhaps I misunderstood. (And this answer probably doesn't make sense only in the context of the original question...)

Comment: no problem, maybe I will post to the eclipse board to see what they think about all this